# Routing problem: Index.html blank after deploying React App on render

Tags: reactjs, deployment, react-router, react-router-dom, render.com

I finished a react project and after deploying it to Render everything is blank. I tried everything I found as solutions to this problem but nothing worked.

To simplify the matter for me and to eliminate other problems, I created a new react project with two components `test.jsx` and `home.jsx`, and `page.jsx` it's simple here is the 3 pages:

Page.jsx

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <div>
      <a href='/home'>
        <div>home</div>
      </a>
      <a href='/test'>
        <div>test</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Test.jsx

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Test() {
  return (
    <div>test component</div>
  )
}
```

Home.jsx

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>home component</div>
  )
}
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Test from './Test';
import Home from './Home';
import Page from './Page';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';


function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Page />}/>
        <Route path='/test' element={<Test />} />
        <Route path='/home' element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my project folder structure :

[image]

I tried changing inside `package.json` and add `"homepage" : "."` but it didn't work. I tried adding Rewrites/Redirects rules in Render's settings from `"/*"` to `"/index.html"` but also it didn't work. I even tried using `HashRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter` and also the same problem still.

The issue arises when I go to [mywebsite/](https://testsite-a71m.onrender.com/); it displays the `page.jsx` but no other pages. Additionally, when I click on "home" or "test," it redirects me to a blank index.html. The same issue occurs if I type [mywebsite/home](https://testsite-a71m.onrender.com/home). It's routing problem but I see no problem from my view.

Comment: What server do you use? It seems that you server handles requests like `/home` and `/test`. But desired behaviour is that the server always responds with the React app, no matter what route is

Comment: @Eugene, it's on render hosting

Comment: I'm sure it's a redirection rule issue. And actually, you've attached the invalid rule. The path to "index.html" should start with a slash: "/index.html". Have you tried this?

Comment: @Eugene Yes, I did it's the same problem

Comment: `"https://testsite-a71m.onrender.com/"` appears to return a 404. Are you ***sure*** you've setup the render configuration correctly to host your app?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, the configuration was correctly set up, I was getting the website/ page but no other page, I deleted it and I'm trying to figure out the same solution for the main project,

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are on the right track with setting the redirect rule, but you should be redirecting all page requests to the ***root*** index.html file, e.g. `"/index.html"`.

Add a "Redirect and Rewrite Rules" rule to rewrite all requests from `"/*"` to `"/index.html"`.

> [image]

See the Render [Using Client-Side Routing](https://render.com/docs/deploy-create-react-app#using-client-side-routing) docs for more details.

Additionally the `Page` component should use the `Link` component instead of raw anchor tags to effect *internal* navigation actions within the app.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to='/home'>
        <div>home</div>
      </Link>
      <Link to='/test'>
        <div>test</div>
      </Link>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that I added this rule but it's the same problem

Comment: @medosem You mentioned adding `"index.html"` as a rule value, not `"/index.html"`. The leading `"/"` is important. Are you saying that you did actually use `"/index.html"` and it's still not working?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying yes, I will correct the path mistake