# Why does my react router make GET request?

Tags: html, reactjs, hosting

Edits:

This is a react app, with a postgres db and an express server. Each hosted on render.com

I have a router on an app with a `/login` route, and a `"PrivateRoute"`, the private route insures the users is signed in before the `Celeb component` is show to them, if they're not signed in they're navigated to the /login page.

PrivateRoute.tsx

```
 function PrivateRoute() {
  const { currentUser }: any = useAuth();

  return currentUser ? <Celebs /> : <Navigate to={"/login"} replace />;
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

App.tsx

```
 <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/" element={<PrivateRoute />} />
          <Route path="/*" element={<PrivateRoute />} />
        </Routes>
```

Now from what I understand, this should handle the /login path by serving the Login component, and any path that doesn't have a match will return the PrivateRoute.

The problem now, is that when I open the deployed version of the app, I'm on the Login page automatically

so: https:/url/login

however if I reload, I get an error "Not Found"

in my console tab I get this error:

```
GET https://url/login 404 (Not Found)
```

Which means I'm making a GET request to the client url(not server).

What am I missing exactly? why is my Login page showing on the opening of the app, but on subsequent re-render I get "Not Found"?

Comment: 404 is a server response, saying that the `login.html` file is not found. Seems like you need to configure your server to always respond with the `index.html` file, which lets react handle the routing on the client side. This is showing on refreshing a deeplink because on your initial request (say to url.com), the server responds with the index file-letting react handle routing. The refresh looks for the `login.html` file because server isn't configured to always respond with the index file

Comment: When you reload the page you make a request to the server based on the current URL, e.g. a GET request for a page hosted on `"https://url/login"`. Since your app is hosted/served from `"https://url/"` the server returns a 404 for the page that doesn't exist in the backend. You need to configure the server to return your root index.html file for all page requests into the app. Where are you deploying the app, what server or hosting service? Please [edit] to clarify. See also [mcve].

Comment: @MichaelAbeln

This is a react app, login is a tsx file. 

from what I understand, my project is served from the client side, what is the point of a router if I'm handling the requests of each route on the server?

The server in my app is used to fetch data, the client is hosted independently from it, and technically works without it.

Comment: @DrewReese

I see, but why am I making a request to the server when my app is served from the client? my front end works independently and only uses the server to fetch data, not pages. I'm hosting the server and client on render.com.

Comment: Pages are served ***to*** browsers, e.g. clients, ***from*** servers. The client requests pages from a server, *somewhere*, and it doesn't matter if that server is running on the same machine or across the universe. When you reload the page, the browser makes a request to the server for it. It's only after the app files have been served to the client ***only then*** does the client-side routing kick in and "navigate" to the correct route/page.

Comment: How are you serving the app? Check the CRA [deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) docs to see if there's a relevant section for the server/hosting service you are using.

Comment: Ok let me clarify.

I have a client, server and a db all hosted on render.com. The client works independently of the server, or I thought, currently my server only fetches data from my server when the client requests it, it doesn't server any pages to the client. 

when I reload, and get a page error, the GET request is send to the client url not the server url, I don't know if this is because I'm not handling it on the server. 

Technically I just have a client app that uses a server to fetch data, the client component should be independent of the server.

Comment: Render.com ***is*** the server hosting the app and serving page quests.  Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77083122/8690857

Comment: sweet, I see now. This makes a lot of sense, and works perfectly. Thank you very much Drew, have a nice day.